# I want to sum the values of a column file and append each sum to the new column in the same csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm new to coding, can you please share detailed code
[This is the given data, I want to iterate in the amount column and each sum to a new column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPYSQ.png)
Like this:
[after adding all these amounts should be in the new column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErBEC.png)
and also I have to find the minimum in the sum and the date of it, maximum in the sum and the date of it.

Actually my question is asked like this

Please apply credit transactions first to calculate balance on a given day.

**Input CSV Format:**

There are multiple customer IDs in the csv file

CustomerID, Date, Amount

**Output Format:**

CustomerID, MM/YYYY, Min Balance, Max Balance, Ending Balance"

Is this the best method to address the query?

Thank you

Comment: Please apply credit transactions first to calculate balance on a given day.  
Input CSV Format:
CustomerID, Date, Amount
Output Format:
CustomerID, MM/YYYY, Min Balance, Max Balance, Ending Balance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to add a cumulative sum column. The `sum` function just adds up all the values in a single column, so it won't fulfil your current requirement.

So instead of `d.['Amounts'].sum()` it would be:

`d['sum'] = d['Amounts'].cumsum()`

From there, you can search that sum column with the `.idxmin()` and `.idxmax()` functions to grab the index of the rows containing the min and max, respectively. Finally, you can index those rows in `d` and grab the associated dates.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, but I have another doubt, there are different customer ids, How to add till the same customer ID and when a new customer ID Starts it should start summing for the next ID Newly Like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r6MrEA6UxAeLrjiLhBVN15jyz4bZPNcg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can use the `groupby` function in conjunction with `cumsum` to group by ID then do individual sums. You can see here for more information: https://www.statology.org/pandas-cumulative-sum-by-group/

Comment: I have another doubt how can I find the min, max and final sum of each customer Id and print it out. Thank you in advance

Comment: I have figured out how to print out min and max but not the final sum of each customer ID and the date of it (In the format MM/YYYY) can you please tell me how to do it? Thank you

Comment: How to get the date format as MM/YYYY for the last sum value of the customer ID ?

Comment: Is there any way to get the date too in MM/YYYY?

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple customers

```
df['sum']=df.groupby(['Date','Customer ID'],as_index=False)['Amount'].cumsum()
df
Out[23]: 
  Customer ID        Date  Amount   sum
0        C231  11-01-2022    9232  9232
1        C231  11-02-2022    6061  6061
2        C231  11-03-2022    5108  5108
3        C231  11-04-2022    9086  9086
4        C232  11-03-2022     100   100
5        C232  11-03-2022     200   300
```

### Min, Max and sum by Customer

```
 df.groupby('Customer ID').agg({'Amount': ['min', 'max','sum']})
Out[25]: 
            Amount             
               min   max    sum
Customer ID                    
C231          5108  9232  29487
C232           100   200    300
```

### Monthly Min, Max and sum by Customer

```
df.groupby([df.Date.dt.strftime('%b/%Y'),'Customer ID']).agg({'Amount':['min','max','sum']}).reset_index()
Out[111]: 
       Date Customer ID Amount             
                           min   max    sum
0  Nov/2022        C231   5108  9232  29487
1  Nov/2022        C232    100   200    300
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, but I have another doubt, there are different customer ids, How to add till the same customer ID and when a new customer ID Starts it should start summing for the next ID Newly Like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r6MrEA6UxAeLrjiLhBVN15jyz4bZPNcg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: updated answer for multiple customers

Comment: I have another doubt how can I find the min, max and final sum of each customer Id and print it out. Thank you in advance

Comment: I have figured out how to print out min and max but not the final sum of each customer ID and the date of it (In the format MM/YYYY) can you please tell me how to do it? Thank you

Comment: But how to get the date format as MM/YYYY for the last sum value of the customer ID

Comment: Is there any way to get the date too in MM/YYYY?